# Changing home directory of user on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'd like to change the home directory of the user that I initially setup on Windows Subsystem for Linux. I found this command

```
sudo usermod -d /mnt/c/Users/Alex alex
```

Which should allow this, however I am getting this error

```
usermod: user alex is currently used by process 2
```

Presumably because I am logged in as that user. I've tried going to root by doing `sudo su -` and then running the command again but I get the same issue. I tried a command I found on Google to log out the user `alex` from root but that also kicked me out of bash entirely.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you not logout of that account, login as another account, and then run the commands to see what result you get?

Comment: Logging out of that account closes Linux bash and gets you back to Windows prompt. Logging back in just puts you by default in that user. And switching to root through `sudo su -` I still get the process error

Comment: I see, I assume you cannot log into the Windows as another account while logged out of that one, and then run the bash command then from that account in bash for the other account? I've not setup bash within Windows yet so just thinking of potential simple solutions even though having to do that would be sort of inconvenient but if it's just a one-time deal then done, maybe it'd work. Quick thoughts only though.

Comment: Unfortunately the bash environment is tied to the current user Windows, stored in %appdata%. So another user will get their own bash environment

Comment: You can change the default user name by executing in Windows (not bash) `lxrun /setdefaultuser myusername`.

Comment: @harrymc I'm trying to change the home directory and not the username, but perhaps there's another such lxrun command for that?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Changing the home directory with WSL is done the same way as in Linux:

1. Enter bash
2. Type the command  `sudo vim /etc/passwd`
3. Find your account's line, which might look like:
   `harry:x:1000:1000:"",,,:/home/harry:/bin/bash`
4. Change the home directory, which above is `/home/harry`, to the new directory, using WSL notation (If you want to set Windows directory as home directory, you need to prepend it with `/mnt/`, like `/mnt/c` for C:/, `/mnt/d` for D:/, etc)
5. Save the file and exit vim by typing `:wq` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Exit bash and re-launch it
7. To test, use the commands:
   `cd ~`
   `pwd`

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I don't know WSL, I'm just curious: in general is it safe to just `vim /etc/passwd`? In Linux we have `vipw` especially for the job.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: I have just started with WSL, but I can say that `sudo /usr/sbin/vipw` does exactly the same as my point 2 above. Changing `/etc/passwd` is as safe as doing it on Linux. Maybe safer because destroying it does not affect Windows logon.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why the only way I could find to edit this was through `usermod`.

Comment: Be careful with this - if you move out of the main fake linux filesystem, you'll find you can't edit file permissions properly.

Comment: @Hippyjim I'm facing the same issue and find out that [this SO anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50856772/1819810) could help (requires Win 10 Insider Build 17063 and above).

Comment: This is definitely not safe, it won't necessarily work and it can break your access to the shell as that user (or any user(s), since they're all in the same file). Depending on how the OS is set up, the easiest way to roll this back might be an OS reinstall. Editing ~/.bashrc is much safer and cleaner.

Comment: @AndrewKoster what edit to `.bashrc` is needed to accomplish the same goal in a safer way?

Comment: @mattwilkie This might vary depending on the shell and the OS but a simple `cd` command at the end of `.bashrc` should do it, if your shell is loading `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 7):

As at 2021, there's a better way to log in as root and change user's home directory:

- Press `Win + R`
- Enter `cmd /C wsl -u root`
- A root terminal will open and now you can use the `usermod -d <path> <user>` command with no problem (e.g. `usermod -d /mnt/c/Users/Alex alex`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try running `lxrun /setdefaultuser root` in command prompt, then change the directory, then change the default user to Alex.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid shown error ("user ... is currently used by process") : the user must not be logged in into wsl VM.

1. into VM : edit /etc/wsl.conf to change default user from "the user to be renamed" to root
2. exit VM
3. terminate VM : wsl -t my_vm
4. execute command : wsl -d my_vm -e usermod ...add_your_args_here...
5. "rollback" of #1 (from root to "new username").

Answer (score 0):

When using answer by [@harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) you need to copy .bashrc to your new homedir.

```
cp <old_bashrc> ~
```