# Recover WSL files from another machine

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a laptop with windows 10 that will no longer boot correctly. It had a WSL distribution of Ubuntu installed. Assuming I remove the drive and attach it to a new windows laptop; how can I back up or recover the files within the WSL distribution?

Edit: I believe the windows version was the latest update (1909).

Comment: What version of Windows 10 were you running.  Edit our question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: If you can access the drive's system partition then you can also use the WSL installation. Or, install a WSL distribution in current Windows and chroot into that attached drive. You can find the previous WSL like this https://superuser.com/a/1280916.